# Compile error while execute on visual studio C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, process

I am using visual studio c++ for writing code. Here is sample example what i have wrote.

I am getting below error msg. Can someone guide me the suggestion to solve below error

> namespace "std" has no member "thread"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include<thread>
#include<windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class bar {
public:
  void foo() {
    std::cout << "hello from member function" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::thread t(&bar::foo, bar());
  t.join();
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to copy-paste the *full* and *complete* build output into the question.

Comment: Never, absolutely never include `<windows.h>` unless you know exactly what you are doing. That header is polluting your namespace with macro definitions which mess everything up

Comment: After cleaning up the code (like removing unnecessary and duplicate header includes) [the code builds and runs fine](https://godbolt.org/z/or6M1zvT1)

Comment: Note: In any _real_ program, it never makes sense to `join` a thread immediately after creating it. The whole point of using threads is for your program to do two or more things _concurrently_ with each other. But your `main()` routine does nothing concurrently with the thread `t`. Normally you would (1) create the thread, (2) _do something else for a while_, and then (3) join the thread.

Answer (score -2):

I also think the way you want to start the thread is not ok.
The object on which you want to call the function must be constructed first.
That object needs to "live" longer then the life-time of the thread.
What you are doing now is trying to pass an instance of the bar class as argument to the foo member function.

Tip:
When using threads, it is good to know about lambda's too. Example:

```
int main()
{
  bar b;
  std::thread t([b&]{b.foo()});
  t.join();
}
```

I often use shared_ptr<> to pass data to a thread. This means the thread can extend the lifetime of the object for the duration of the thread. Useful for avoiding passing references to objects actually living on the stack.

```
int main()
{
    auto ptr = std::make_shared<bar>();
    std::thread t([ptr]{ptr->foo();}); 
    t.join();
}
```

Comment: The temporary object created by `bar()` is moved, keeping it alive is unnecessary. Not temporary objects are copied, also not necessary to keep them alive

Comment: `[b&]` will not compile.

Comment: Your answer does not resolve the original compiler error.